# Neo4j JDBCCypherExecutor blocks thread

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using `neo4j 2.1.5` and using `JDBCCypherExecutor` to post my cypher queries.
often the cypher executor thread gets stuck making the app unusable after sometime.
The only option after sometime is to restart the spark webapp.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

The jstack of one of the blocked thread is

```
"qtp1639509299-63" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe454001000 nid=0x1e0e waiting on condition [0x00007fe564fea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000586cf6e88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.WaitingThread.await(WaitingThread.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:391)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:336)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:114)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:112)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:180)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1136)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1225)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1068)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1044)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1453)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.post(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.commit(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.executeQueries(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:204)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.executeQuery(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:214)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection.executeQuery(Neo4jConnection.java:370)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Neo4jPreparedStatement.java:48)
    at com.zahoor.graph.executor.JdbcCypherExecutor.query(JdbcCypherExecutor.java:28)
```

Comment: I've seen this (but unable to prove consistently) when re-using the same prepared statement i.e. a loop with clearParameters(), setting parameters and then executeQuery(). Are you doing something similar?

Comment: Yes... Something similar.  Based on the facet values revd for the mother query.. I trigger a set of sub queries for each facet.. in separate threads parallely.. Wait for all threads to return.. Construct a response and send back..

Comment: But I use separate prepare statements.. Not clear params

Comment: Re-using the same Connection object for all these threads? That's another case where I've seen it die after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate threads might be the issue here, as the JDBC driver keeps the transaction in a thread local, so if you spawn new threads it creates new transaction objects and new connections (if you don't reuse the same `Connection` instance.

And the default pooling of HttpClient is (afaik) 10 parallel connections.

Comment: Yes it was... I created separate connections and now it works fine.

Comment: Does that mean you create  an object of JdbcCypherExecutor per thread? If so, do we require to close the connections once it completes. Or maintain a object pool?